# Grammar regexes match independently but not together

Tags: grammar, raku

This is my attempt to solve the weekly challenge, "implement brace expansion".
I wrote below grammar, which should work. But doesn't.

```
grammar BraceExpansion
{
    regex TOP          { <start-txt> <to-expand> <end-txt> }
    regex start-txt    { <save-char>* }
    regex end-txt      { <save-char>* }
    token save-char    { <-[ \" \& \( \) \` \' \; \< \> \| ]> }
    token list-element { <-[ \" \! \$ \& \( \) \` \' \; \< \> \| ]> }
    token alphanum     { <[ a..z A..Z 0..9 ]> }
    token alpha        { <[ a..z A..Z ]> }
    regex num          { \-? <[ 0..9 ]>+ }
    regex to-expand    { <range> | <list>  }
    regex range        { <alpha-range> | <num-range> }
    regex num-range    { \{ <num>  \. \. <num> [ \. \. <num> ]? \} }
    regex alpha-range  { \{ <alpha> \. \. <alpha> [ \. \.<num> ]? \} }
    regex list         { \{ <list-element>+ % ',' \} }
}

say brace-expand( 'A{1..3}B{a..g..3}C{1,2}D' );

sub num-range( $match )
{
    say "-NUM-";
    my @num = |$match<range><num-range><num>.list>>.Int;
    my @range = @num[0] ... @num[1];
    my $steps = ( @num[2] // 1 ).abs;
    @range.batch( $steps )>>.[0];
}


sub alpha-range( $match )
{
    say "-ALPHA-";
    my @num = |$match<range><alpha-range><alpha>.list>>.Str;
    my @range = @num[0] ... @num[1];
    my $steps = ( $match<range><alpha-range><num> // 1 ).abs;
    @range.batch($steps)>>.[0];
}

sub list( $match )
{
    say "-LIST-";
    $match<list><list-element>.list>>.Str;
}

sub brace-expand( $str )
{
    say "brace-expand( $str )";

    my $match = BraceExpansion.parse( $str );

    my @alternatives =
        $match<range><num-range>   ?? num-range( $match )   !!
        $match<range><alpha-range> ?? alpha-range( $match ) !!
        $match<list>               ?? list( $match )        !!
        ();

    say "A", @alternatives;

    return $str
        unless @alternatives;

    @alternatives
         .map( -> $element { $match<start-txt>.Str ~ $element ~ $match<end-txt>.Str } )
         .map( -> $result  { brace-expand( $result ) } )
    ;
}
```

However, if I change the TOP rule to

```
    regex TOP          { <start-txt> <range> <end-txt> }
```

or

```
    regex TOP          { <start-txt> <list> <end-txt> }
```

the `range` and the `list` tokens work independently and I get the output I expect. But when I use the `to-expand` rule, the whole grammar doesn't match and I cannot figure out why. Is the alteration wrong? But if so, why then does `<alpha-range> | <num-range>` work?

*.... (time passes) ....*

In the meantime I found out that

```
regex TOP           { <start-txt> [ <range> | <list> ] <end-txt> }
```

does what I want. But my question still stands, why doesn't it work as above?

Comment: Did you try and use Grammar::Trace to check where it stops parsing?

Comment: Please review [MRE].

Answer (score 3):

The match is happening fine; you are not indexing into the match correctly. The structure of the resulting match is:

```perl6
start-txt => ｢A{1..3}B{a..g..3}C｣
  save-char => ｢A｣
  ...
to-expand => ｢{1,2}｣
  list => ｢{1,2}｣  # (or range)
  ...
end-txt => ｢D｣
  save-char => ｢D｣
  ...
```

But you are indexing into this like `$match<list>`. You should first be indexing into the `<to-expand>` like `$match<to-expand><list>`. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nVVdb9owFH3nV1wQG8lG3NJJkyYglG6TVqnbKrV7GUaaaS1ASwJyTEUX6F9n/kxsSlttFg@xfc6591xf7CVlyfvdbspImhIGZ4zc0M/rJcny@SKrFTUQg9EpXcP190soRwG9nBPGI77mMfT4IqKSdCu@aXarV7cOuQRbMrmj0c2MsPiNhzPkKsgjHF/8phmU6wYXjQA3AL8GHAAOAf8C3ALcBdwDHAPewDj2@Mk85xFNaEoz7vDrgJv/oEKS5Yxkq9RmOwKC0B8YIvQTjhH6cBDvlNDFj/2CWVUDxdFAwo3oWw9aFt@oMpJNaQwb6EmXvqzaczJQGUUVQ4S1s71sopIqsikUMgbASP70ZOTNxgPAW0/EiWVF1FJseWZmdJ6SkabcyhTapz1NUZxX0Gq3NG1bq@XkHiayrU2VAmgNiw5C77ZnhSj/VH59LDrtk@2nFoRdQVhNKsMBNFPCb2YQmj@DlGtE3358jRpdtZDew6k8rT5sNNQcgFNLZQWp04jRecYroq5GXymMjseAENLfnXEJauacLnMBCvTWyRiOjqADISKTXKO0DprI8IElhCKY0OzKIihTzgE8YWt4cfll@KIxt2nMoVlzV5z9t7lngqhWeNa01nEtS8cyqyesXpxfXVunJrLy4DeT58uI@s0kAjNf@tC@CFQ61tn09@5atCQspxZfwU9JwinLCJ/fUVGnmu18k3N18z5uO4EaDB63sntbhwJTr78s6t0TQvRAK/myz4rqe8kfQtQ9rf0k1XBEA1siVfJho@0XymwyylcsUzUtmassoXl@EO6tlQRAKVkGEMXQrF4Mk2X1CMoWgYcK8mAh9j1UgK1olQO6jOarhMvrbK95zEZYEkUX7nZ/AQ)

The reason the modified version works is that you are removing that intermediate step of `to-expand` so that the index works.